# How to use ldapsearch with SSL on different port (-p does not work)?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

I have an OpenLDAP server running in a test environment with a firewall on the LAN forwarding port 8636 back to slapd listening on 636 (for an older application which does not support START_TLS).

To test things, I started on the LAN by specifying `-p 8636` in the comamand line. This failed for some reason, so I went ahead and tried the same command on the LDAP server itself. I get the same error:

```
ldap1# ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap1 -p 8636
ldapsearch: -H incompatible with -p
```

Huh? Why is this a problem? 
If I don't specify a port number, then it all works OK:

```
ldap1# ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap1
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
...
```

Is there any other way to tell `ldapsearch` to use SSL on a different port or have I missed something in the syntax?

**UPDATE per answer**

```
ldap1# ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap1:636
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
```

...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `ldapsearch: -H incompatible with -p`
>   Huh? Why is this a problem?

You either use the deprecated `-h` and `-p` to respectively set the hostname and non-default port number,
or you use `-H` with a properly [RFC 2255](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2255.txt) specified URL `<scheme>://<hostname>[:portnumber]` to set a non-standard port e.g. `ldaps://ldap1:8636`